# Indefinite integral in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

What would be an unbounded set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that every constant is integrable on $A$? Find a continuous function $A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is not integrable on $A$.

I think that $A = \{0\} \times \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}$ would be a set like that. A function that is not integrable on $A$ would be $f(x, y,z) = z$. Would that be correct? If not do you have any suggestions? How would I prove that that function is not integrable?

Comment: You need a 3D integral, not a 1D one.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? I don't exactly understand.

Comment: Your $A$ is one-dimensional. Its volume is $0$. A 3D integral of any function on it is $0$.

Comment: Oh yes! I see now, yes.

Comment: Let $h:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ satisfy $0<\int_{\mathbb{R}}h(z)\,\mathrm{d}z<\infty$ and let $$A=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2\leq h(z)\}.$$ Then the volume of $A$ is $\pi\int_{\mathbb{R}}h(z)\,\mathrm{d}z$. Of course, for your favorite choice of $h(z)$, you would certainly find an example of $f$ which is not integrable on $A$.